# How do populate the "Roll" field with the results of "turn" in a JFrame window

Tags: java

Here's what I've done so far ... the code snippet which I am trying inside CalculateButtonHandler class.

```
private class CalculateButtonHandler implements ActionListener
{
  public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
  {
     //String strTurn = Turn();
     //int Turn = Int.parseInt(strTurn);        
     int diceRollOne = (int)(Math.random() * 6) + 1;
     int diceRollTwo = (int)(Math.random() * 6) + 1;
     int Turn = diceRollOne + diceRollTwo;

     //yourRollTF.setText(Turn);
  }
 }
```

Comment: Fix your formatting, please!

Comment: did you add `yourRollTF` to the `JPanel`?

Comment: What exactly is the issue you are facing? That within the `actionPerformed` that `yourRollTF` is not accessible? That it doesn't update?

Comment: im trying to design a game of craps in j frame that will show what a player rolled in one panel what their point is in another panel with a roll and quit button. i've got all the panels set up but i dont know how to get the results of "turn" to populate the your roll text pane.

Comment: Is the `yourRollTF` on the JPanel as @flkes asked? When it is uncommented in the code you gave, is it not displaying, giving a compile error, giving a runtime error? There is insufficient information provided to do anything but hazard guesses. And, I think the game of craps cares not just about the total score, but the way in which the score was achieved (an 8 may be "4,4" or "6,2", but there are different payouts). Setting a sum may not be what you need.

Comment: its saying that "turn" is not a string so i cant output it to the "your roll" pane i've created.